# Closed-form solution to $y''=-1/y^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$y''=-c/y^2,$$ describing the motion of a ball you throw straight up in the air, high enough that you can't assume the force of gravity is constant.

We certainly can't solve it by any method we cover in class, nor by any method I know. I like to show how we can derive conservation of energy and hence escape velocity from the DE even though we can't solve it. But

**Question:** Can anyone state definitively that there is in fact no closed-form solution? (For general initial conditions...)

**Edit:** Thanks to various comments, I realize I was being a little dumb - I had conservation of energy, which, as I should have realized years ago, is actually a separable first-order equation, leading at least to implicit solutions: It's easy to see that $$\left(\frac12(y')^2-\frac cy\right)'=0,$$so
$$\frac12(y')^2-\frac cy=k,$$which is separable. (You end up with an integral that's basically $$\int\frac{dy}{(1+1/y)^{1/2}},$$with a few irrelevant constants. The idiot-freshman substitution $u=(1+1/y)^{1/2}$ converts that to the integral of a rational function...)

Comment: Guessing a solution of the form $y = a t^b$, I find $y = (9/2)^{1/3} t^{2/3}$ is a solution.  More generally, $y = (9/2)^{1/3} (t+C)^{2/3}$ is a solution.  (Still not enough parameters to give the general solution, though.)

Comment: Though interestingly enough, that solution does appear to be precisely the escape velocity case: $-\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{2} (y')^2 \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: I'm not sure where the $c$ went in this escape velocity case, but I don't see why this is hard to solve. If we have $y(y')^2 = 2c$, this means (assuming $y>0$) $\sqrt y y' = \sqrt{2c}$, and this integrates immediately.

Comment: Maple's solution involves solving a transcendental (but non-differential) equation.

Comment: Yes, the general first integral (giving $y'$) will have another constant of integration which makes the integral non-elementary. A few of us were discussing the case where that constant is set equal to $0$.

Comment: BTW, for this to be correct the ball has to be thrown from the north or south poles; otherwise the rotation of the Earth (and associated Coriolis effect etc.) has to be taken into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are implicit solutions
$$ t = a + c k^3 \ln\left(c k^2 + y + \sqrt{y^2 + 2 c k^2 y}\right) - k \sqrt{y^2 + 2 c k^2 y}$$
and
$$ t = a - c k^3 \ln\left(c k^2 + y + \sqrt{y^2 + 2 c k^2 y}\right) + k \sqrt{y^2 + 2 c k^2 y}$$

But we would not expect these to have explicit closed-form solutions for $y$ as functions of $t$.

Comment: How do you get that? Which method?

Comment: Change $dy/dt$ to $dt/dy$?

Comment: The second can be obtained from the first by $k\to -k$.

Comment: @W.mu I don't know where he got those, but see edit to the question for one way to obtain implicit solutions.